# Modification in $_REQUEST response or any alternative to get correct value in array using explode

Tags: php, arrays

In my application there are different promotions and usera can answer to that promotions using single or multi choice questions. I am using following logic and it works fine except one problem:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($questions);$i++)
{
     if($questions[$i][type_of_question] == 'multiple_choice')
     {
         $options_array = explode(",", $_REQUEST["que".$questions[$i][id]]);
     }

     // Code here which insert answers in database table
 }
```

This line of code:

```
$options_array = explode(",", $_REQUEST["que".$questions[$i][id]]);
```

this code shows comma seperated answers of the questions. For example:

Example 1: test1,test2,test3 [This scenario works fine]

Example 2: yes,no,I am not interested(cricket,footbal)

Example 2 has shows the problem e.g. if there is , inside the choice option. Php explode function break and values according to , so in this case I gets 4 array elements.

```
Array[0] => yes
Array[1] => no
Array[3] => I am not interested(cricket
Array[4] => footbal
```

while I required following:

```
Array[0] => yes
Array[1] => no
Array[3] => I am not interested(cricket,footbal)
```

How can I fix this problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: By not using , to join the answers. You cannot use any character as a delimiter that can appear in the answers.

Comment: I think correct way is to store user's answers in array too. That could be done by corresponding html-code for gathering answers (use `[]` for that)

Comment: Use a delimiter that isn't a "normal" character like `|`.

Comment: $_REQUEST["que".$questions[$i][id]] returning me values seperated by , so how can I use any other delemator to seperator? Is there any way that I can get $_REQUEST values using |?

Comment: How does your  multiple choice input looks like? Because you need a different approach to solve this problem. I believe your passing it wrong like@AlmaDoMundo said.

Comment: Muliple choice input option can be single worrd, two word or even one sentence, there can be special characters i.e. (), etc. I have to store exact the same answer.

Comment: Well pass your multiple choice with and extra array  name="multiple[]", thats why im asking for your htlm markup.  Simple html code a few lines.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix the way the data is being fed in from the front-end: there's no way in this code alone to fix this problem.  For example, you could have the input `yes, no, maybe`, and it could be either `yes`, `no`, `maybe`, or `yes`, `no, maybe`.

You need to perform some consistent encoding or escaping on the front-end so you can uniquely access the records. You haven't told us how it's submitted on the front, but just joining the answers together with commas won't be enough. You could try escaping the commas in the fields!